# MySQL: Allocation of limited seats among students based on first-come first-serve basis

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, allocation, ranking

imagine a college where students get to enroll into courses online via a website.
Each course may have a specified maximum number of admitted students, and admission is based on who registers first.
For example in an "Art" class with 15 available seats, only the 15 students who registered first for that course via the website would get in.

There are basically three MySQL tables:
users (in fact students with uid as the unique user id)
courses (course specs like title and class size; the cid (course id) is the primary key)
links_users_courses (will contain three columns uid,cid,reg_date, which reg_date is a datetime variable reflecting when user uid registered for course cid)

I'm now looking for a MySQL solution to the problem of displaying to user A (uid=100) not only a list of all courses he attempted to get a seat in, which would be straightforward along the lines of

```
select cid,coursetitle from links_users_courses left join courses using(cid) where uid=100
```

but also whether he got in a course or not, that is, whether his time rank was below each course's specified class size.

In the end, he should be displayed three columns: course id (cid), coursetitle and status (enlisted,waitlisted), where waitlisted would mean he's lies beyond the threshold for a given class.

Answer (score 0):

You **could** do this all in one SQL query (and if you really want I'll put it together for you), but I don't think many would recommend it.  You need to think a little about your process, I would suggest.  Are you using a procedural languages to generate your output (php, python etc.)?  If so, you might be much better off taking a more functional approach.  Another approach, if you want to stay very close to the db, would be to use VIEWs to deal with some of the intermediate stages.  But doing it all in one SQL query is probably not the way to go (except, perhaps, as an exercise).

Comment: @Galz: since when is the homework tag not allowed anymore? It has 6623 entries in it right now.

Comment: Hi, I'm using PHP 5.3 as procedural language. I would be happy to see any (or both) types of solutions you refer to, especially the SQL-only version that would be more difficult for me to figure out by myself then the procedural one.